# NuGet: how to insert file to references

Tags: c#, manifest, nuget-package

My .NET 4.0 application use set of unmanaged dlls with COM objects and *.manifest file.
Now this manifest file used in References and dlls always copied to output folder.
The manifest file describes COM objects and used for in-place register.
I want to create a NuGet package and replace direct reference with NuGet Package.

How I can add this manifest file to NuGet package and it must be in csproj as a reference?